# pull в workingDirectory вместо создания новых папок под каждую ветку

Tags: c#, git, unity3d, непрерывная-интеграция, teamcity

Разрабатываем игровой проект, решили настроить CI и билдить сразу несколько конфигураций(сервер, клиент, dev-версии..) Но столкнулись с проблемой, при которой решение из коробки teamcity для работы с ветками не дает хороших эффектов. Дело в том что проект вместе с контентом занимает 40+ гб, все это дело лежит в git'е + подобие GitFlow, т.е куча веток которые хотелось бы тоже билдить непрерывно. Плюс ко всему, подливает масло в огоно Unity3d с его кешем который не желательно трекать git'ом.
 В итоге выходит что при добавлении новой ветки происходит следующее:

1. TC делает новую папку checoutDir.
2. миррорит туда весь проект(40+ гб да и еще 2+ часа)
3. потом Unity начинает реимпортить весь проект, что дает еще +40 гб кеша и 5-6 часов времени.
4. после всего возможно что какие-нибудь ссылки полетят и рабочего билда вовсе не будет.

Хотелось бы сделать так:

1. TC приходит триггер, запускается конфигурация на агентах
2. Агент возможно переходит нужную ветку и пулит все коммиты.
3. запускаем unity, билдим))

Только вот как это сделать? гугл ничего не говорит, а документация по TC очень запутаная.

Comment: А вы бинарные файлы храните в git? Почему такой большой размер репозитория?

Comment: У меня тимсити по умолчанию переключает одну и ту же папку между ветками, а не чекаутит заново, по крайней мере в режиме agent side checkout. Покажите хотя бы скрины настроек.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g4ousa - настройки конфигурации. версия ТС - 2017.1.3 (build 46961).

Comment: Да, бинарные храним там же. Пока руки не дошли до Git-lfs. У нас много контента. Но дело даже не в этом, дело в кеше который Unity так любит долго делать...

Comment: В таком конфиге  teamcity должен использовать одну и ту же папку на агенте. Стоит посмотреть логи агента, и поискать в какой момент он решает забирать в новую рабочую папку. Ну и в саппорт тимсити  написать - это ж вполне платный продукт, они быстро отвечают, даже для бесплатных версий.